# Возможно ли сейчас написать нормальный клиент Вконтакте для старых телефонов на платформе java? :)

Tags: java, vkontakte-api, mobile, j2me

Заказал себе Sony Ericsson k610i J2ME (MIDP).

Интересно, позволяет ли сейчас API Vk нормально с этим работать.

Comment: Нету специалистов по данной категории?) Аль вымерли таковые?)

Comment: Как вы представляете себе HTTP API, которое фильтрует пользователей по языкам программирования, и одних допускает, а других нет?

Comment: Ну технически то можно нормальный месседжер вк создать на телефон старый?

Comment: @PHPcoder, да, вполне. Никаких проблем технического характера для этого нет. Да, будут ограничения самого устройства - видео в mp4 не посмотреть на нем, например, да и фотографии на таком экране не особо приятно будет рассматривать, но в остальном - можно сделать вполне себе полноценный клиент.

Comment: @PHPCoder, привет! Предлагаю вместе написать такую штуку! Давайте спишемся в соц. сетях? :)